# LyX Beamer: Break Large Table into Multiple Frames

Tags: tables, beamer, lyx

I have a slide deck made with the Beamer ornate template. One of the slides contains a very large table that cannot fit on one slide. Is there a way to make it span multiple slides without having to manually break up the table?

For reference, I'm using LyX 2.2.2, so I can't write actual LaTeX code to solve this problem

I'd appreciate any help on the matter

Comment: Please think twice before you include such large tables in your presentation - is this the best way to convey the information to your audience?

Comment: @samcarter: while I would normally agree with your criticism, this is a highly technical presentation, and that table is indeed fully relevant, and does need to be included in my presentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tab in the Table Settings box for exactly this purpose. Clicking on the `Multi-Page` tab lets you turn this into a table that spans multiple slides. It even has options to keep the table header on each slide, etc

[image]